# Multiple outputs suddenly not writing any output?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce

Suddenly multiple outputs not writing any output to the destination.

I use a custom implementation of multiple outputs, where, I just changed:

```
  if((ch == '/') || (ch == ':')||(ch == '-')||(ch =='.'))
      {
          continue;
      }
```

in the method, as shown below. But the same was working all along, and suddenly it is not working. It is not writing anything to the output directory:

/home/users/mlakshm/

pls help!!!

```
 private static void checkTokenName(String namedOutput) {
    if (namedOutput == null || namedOutput.length() == 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Name cannot be NULL or emtpy");
    }
    for (char ch : namedOutput.toCharArray()) {
      if ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z')) {
        continue;
      }
      if ((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z')) {
        continue;
      }
      if ((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9')) {
        continue;
      }
      if((ch == '/') || (ch == ':')||(ch == '-')||(ch =='.'))
      {
          continue;
      }
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Name cannot be have a '" + ch + "' char");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where, exactly, are you writing output to that directory?

Comment: Well are you getting an exception?

Comment: I am not getting any exception. But nothing is being written

Comment: What is input String?

Comment: @MahalakshmiLakshminarayanan But you're not writing anything..

Comment: @Jeffrey, Sachin   I am just writing   mos.getCollector("/home/users/mlakshm/RemFile/rfile, reporter).collect(new Text(str_key), new Text(key_val));   The str_key, and str_val, I even gave some string like: "hi" in that place, but no use. Output folder is getting created, but nothing is being written. I am wondering if this is some issue related to not enough space being available in dfs.

Answer (score 0):

As you may notice the method `checkTokenName()` is to make sure that the output name is valid. Now, you are trying to modify the very integral part of `MultipleOutputs` which you shouldn't. There are a number of reasons that characters like `/`,`:`,`.` and `-` aren't allowed in the first place:

1. Many file systems doesn't allow some of these characters in a *filename*
2. Using MultipleOutputs, one may write to multiple *files* but in a designated directory, not at any desired location.
3. As you may have noticed, for a following named output:

   // Defines additional single text based output 'text' for the job
    MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "text", TextOutputFormat.class,
    LongWritable.class, Text.class);
   The output file names would be text-0000, text0001 etc.

So if you want to write in different directories, then better go for overriding `MultipleTextOutputFormat`; and if you aren't in liberty of using old API, then you better write to [HDFS](https://sites.google.com/site/hadoopandhive/home/how-to-write-a-file-in-hdfs-using-hadoop)/[S3](http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) yourself rather than relying on hadoop to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. The guidelines were useful. The multipleoutputs was working fine. I made a mistake in the configure method, which reads the files written using multiple outputs via distributed cache. I used configure(conf, reprter) instead of configure(conf), so the program never entered configure method, and no files were read and i mistook it as no files were written by multiple outputs.